# Prevent dragged object from leaving view its assigned to

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to write a piece of code in iOS using swift that creates a square where the user touches and lets them drag it around. The catch is I want the area it can move around in to be confined to the UIView it was created it.

The code below *almost* works. You can only create the square by pressing within the box, but then you can just drag it where you want. I'm not picky about if the box stays in the "fence" and tracks with your finger or just disappears until you move your finger back in, but I can't have it all over the screen.

I'm pretty new to this, so if there's a better way to go about it, I'm happy to be corrected.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var dragableSquare = UIView()   // a square that will appear on press and be dragged around
var fence = UIView()            // a view that the square should be confined within

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // define the fence UIView and it to view
    fence.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.width/2 - 100, view.frame.height/2 - 100, 200, 200)
    fence.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    view.addSubview(fence)

    // give the fence a gesture recognizer
    var pressRecog = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "longPress:")
    pressRecog.minimumPressDuration = 0.001
    fence.addGestureRecognizer(pressRecog)
}


func longPress(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    print("press!")

    // get location of the press
    var touchPoint = gesture.locationInView(fence)

    // When the touch begins place the square at that point
    if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {
        print("began")

        // create and add square to fence view
        dragableSquare.frame = CGRectMake(touchPoint.x-5, touchPoint.y-5, 10, 10)
        dragableSquare.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        self.fence.addSubview(dragableSquare)


    // While the press continues, update the square's location to the current touch point
    } else {
        print("moving")
        dragableSquare.center = touchPoint
    }
}
```

I just joined stack overflow and I've been really impressed with how generous and helpful the community is. I hope I'll get enough experience to start helping others out soon too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CGRectIntersection to get the size of the intersection rectangle between to views. In your case, you want to keep moving the square as long as the intersection rectangle between the square and the fence is the same size as the square (meaning the square is still wholly within the fence). So your else clause should look like this,

```
} else {
    print("moving")
        if CGRectIntersection(dragableSquare.frame, fence.bounds).size == dragableSquare.frame.size {
            dragableSquare.center = touchPoint
        }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly the solution I was looking for! Thank you so much. I was able to modify it just a little bit so the square snaps to the users finger if they bring it back into the box before finishing the press. 

Thank you so much! I had been mulling over that for a couple days and it was driving me crazy.

I noticed that you fence.frame doesn't work in in place of fence.bounds. Do you know why that is?

Comment: @ErikHornberger, you need to use frame for the square because its bounds origin will always be 0,0. Since the fence's bounds are also 0,0 the intersection would always be the size of the square. The square's frame is the fence's frame of reference (since it's a subview), so that's what you need to look at to know where the square is relative to the fence.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! That makes perfect sense.